The build tools for v143 (Platform Toolset = 'v143') cannot be found
I am upgrading my application build environment from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022. As VS2019 uses Platform toolset v142 while VS2022 uses platform toolset v143, I will have to change platform toolset of all the projects (around 400 projects) in my application. So instead, I am using Directory.build.targets (placed in the root directory) file to overwrite the platform toolset in all my project files
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

But when building projects I am facing this issue. I am sure I have installed all the v143 build related tools from Visual Studio Installer.
error MSB8020: The build tools for v143 (Platform Toolset = 'v143') cannot be found. To build using the v143 build tools, please install v143 build tools.
When I am removing the Directory.build.targets file and manually changing the project file from <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset> to <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset> its working fine.
What can be the issue ??

I suggest you double-check the version of VS you used to open the project. Under my tests, you can't install v143 for the 2019 version in Visual Studio Installer, you can only install it for the 2022 version. In this case, after I upgraded the project file in 2019 to v143 version, opening it with vs2019 will cause you to get the error you said, but opening it with vs2022 works normally.

I am using VS2022 only, I dont have VS2019 installed

During my testing, I encountered no issues when upgrading the VS2019 project using Directory.build.targets. However, it seems to be problematic on your computer. I recommend reinstalling your VS2022 to see if that resolves the issue.
